# Unhandled exception at 0x00b21840 in tester.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, mysql

```
BOOL bLoadActions()
{
    int iIndex = 0;
    int iRows;
    int iFields;
    MYSQL_ROW myRow;
    MYSQL_FIELD* field [200];

    for (int a = 0; a < 200; a++)
        field[a] = NULL;

mysql_query(con, "SELECT * FROM `cq_action`;");
res= mysql_store_result(con);
if ((iRows = (int)mysql_num_rows(res)) > 0)
{
    iFields = (WORD)mysql_num_fields(res);
    for(int b = 0; b < iRows; b++)
    {
        myRow = mysql_fetch_row(res);//<=== error here
        mysql_field_seek(res, 0);
        for(int f = 0; f < iFields; f++)
        {
            field[f] = mysql_fetch_field(res);
            if(field[f]) {
            if(!strcmp(field[f]->name, "id"))
            {
                iIndex++;
                m_pActionList[iIndex] = new class CAction;
                m_pActionList[iIndex]->id = atoi(myRow[f]);
                m_pActionList[iIndex]->index = iIndex;
            }
            else if(!strcmp(field[f]->name, "param"))
            {
                m_pActionList[iIndex]->param = new char[strlen(myRow[f])+1];
                m_pActionList[iIndex]->param[strlen(myRow[f])] = 0;
                memcpy(m_pActionList[iIndex]->param, myRow[f], strlen(myRow[f]));
            }
            else if(!strcmp(field[f]->name, "type"))
                m_pActionList[iIndex]->type = atoi(myRow[f]);
            else if(!strcmp(field[f]->name, "id_next"))
                m_pActionList[iIndex]->idnext = atoi(myRow[f]);
            else if(!strcmp(field[f]->name, "id_nextfail"))
                m_pActionList[iIndex]->idfail = atoi(myRow[f]);
            else if(!strcmp(field[f]->name, "data"))
                m_pActionList[iIndex]->data = atoi(myRow[f]);
            }
            else{
                if(field[f]=NULL)
                    cout<<"error"<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

return 0;
```

}
idk every thing seems good.... but i get this error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00b21840 in tester.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

after the edit the errors happens here `myRow = mysql_fetch_row(res);//<=== error here`

Comment: You are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer; my bets are on the line `field[f] = mysql_fetch_field(res);` for the `NULL` assignment and of the next line for the error itself.

Comment: @Matteo Italia- didnt get what you mean sorry!!

Comment: @Matteo: As indicated by the comment in the source this is the line where the error occurs. I guess the main question is *why* there is a NULL pointer returned by `mysql_fetch_field(res)`.

Comment: @sth: IIRC, the very first version of this question didn't have that indication, otherwise I wouldn't have written such a comment.

Comment: @Matteo Italia,@sth- after the edit the errors happens here `myRow = mysql_fetch_row(res);//<=== error here`

Comment: What's `res`? Where's `res` declared? Why are your variable declarations all bundled up at the beginning of the function?

Answer (score 1):

It means one of the pointers is null when it is dereferenced. Attach a debugger, it will tell you which line the error occurs on.

Comment: @Sjoerd- `if(!strcmp(field[f]->name, "id")){// <= error happens here`

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you're most likely dereferencing a `NULL` pointer coming from `mysql_fetch_field`. You should change your code to something like this:

```
            for(int f = 0; f < m_fields; f++){ 
                field[f] = mysql_fetch_field(res);
                if(field[f]) {
                  if(!strcmp(field[f]->name, "id")){// <= error happens here
                      iIndex++;
                      m_pNpcList[iIndex] = new class CNpc;
                      m_pNpcList[iIndex]->m_iID = atoi(row[f]);
                  }
                } else {
                  //field[f] is NULL, do some error handling here
                }
            }
```

Comment: after the edit the errors happens here `myRow = mysql_fetch_row(res);//<=== error here`